# SDN4 : How to add multiple custom labels to a NodeEntity

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

Prior to using SDN 4, I used custom REST client code to implement my own DAO layer between client & Neo4j db. I was able to add a number of labels to nodes I created. This also appears to have been possible using SDN 3 from what I can deduce from docs & other questions using the @Labels annotation.

However, @Labels does not appear to be supported in SDN 4 and the SDN 4 documentation implies that only the class name of an entity class (and any super classes) will be added to a node entity on creation.

Is there a way to add additional labels to a node? I need the values of such labels to be supplied by the user, not hard coded in an annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An unmanaged extension would be the way to do it currently. When a node is created, the extension can assign the additional labels as required. You could either write an unmanaged extension directly or build a [GraphAware Runtime Module](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/tree/master/runtime)